# Does a Spellslinger shoot actual bullets when casting spells? Can they use Named Bullets?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Does a Spellslinger shoot actual bullets when casting spells? The wording goes like "In a spellslinger’s hands, they both fire projectiles (bullets and pellets) and cast magic" but to me it is unclear if it means that she can shoot bullets and cast spells or shoot bullets with spells in it.

If the spellslinger shoots actual bullets with spells, she can use named bullet to have a sure crit with, for example, a scorching ray?

Answer (score 2):

## No.

The line you quoted (*"they both fire projectiles ... and cast magic"*) means that they are able to do both, not that they can do both *in the same action*.

The Spellslinger can either shoot a bullet with his gun as an attack (including as part of a full attack), or cast a valid spell as a spellcasting action. In the latter case, you don't deal bullet damage, don't need ammunition, and can't use a named bullet.

For something that works similarly to what you describe, you should check the [Eldritch Archer](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/archetypes/paizo-magus-archetypes/eldritch-archer-magus-archetype) magus archetype.